# I am receiving a php error when I access my magento site

Tags: php, mysql, magento

When I attempt to access my magento site or admin panel I receive this error:

```
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '__DIR__/composer/autoload_real.php' (include_path='/homepages/1/d372694303/htdocs/Magento 1.8/app/code/local:/homepages/1/d372694303/htdocs/Magento 1.8/app/code/community:/homepages/1/d372694303/htdocs/Magento 1.8/app/code/core:/homepages/1/d372694303/htdocs/Magento 1.8/lib:.:/usr/lib/php5') in /homepages/1/d372694303/htdocs/Magento 1.8/app/code/local/Elite/vendor/autoload.php on line 5
```

All I did was disable all caching from the admin panel and now I cannot access the site. Is there a way to re-enable caching? I attempted to re-enable caching via phpmyadmin with the sql command

```
UPDATE `core_cache_option` SET value=1;
```

This did not solve my problem.

Comment: It would appear that a reference to the [`__DIR__`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) magic constant has been placed within a string literal, rather than concatenated to it.  Alternatively, if you are using a version of PHP prior to v5.3.0 (in which that constant was added), then any reference to it [will implicitly be treated](http://php.net/language.constants.syntax) as an (unquoted) string literal instead.

Comment: Would have this been something I changed? Also which file would that most likely be located in? I apologize I know very little about php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an error specific to your system.  Either custom development, weird stuff done m third party extensions, or both.

PHP provides you with all the information you need to debug your error.

If you parse apart your error message, first there's the error

> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '**DIR**/composer/autoload_real.php'

As others have pointed out, the magic constant `__DIR__` is being included literally in a string.

Second, in parenthesis, PHP lets you know the include paths during the request

```
(include_path='
/homepages/1/d372694303/htdocs/Magento 1.8/app/code/local:
/homepages/1/d372694303/htdocs/Magento 1.8/app/code/community:
/homepages/1/d372694303/htdocs/Magento 1.8/app/code/core:
/homepages/1/d372694303/htdocs/Magento 1.8/lib:.:
/usr/lib/php5')
```

These look pretty standard (although personally I wouldn't include a space in your "Magento 1.8" path name, but I'm old)

Third, and finally, PHP tells you **where** the error happened.

> in /homepages/1/d372694303/htdocs/Magento 1.8/app/code/local/Elite/vendor/autoload.php on line 5

So line 5 of `app/code/local/Elite/vendor/autoload.php` is where the error occurred.

As to **why** it occurred, it looks like someone is trying to use composer to install something in the Elite folder.  This could be how the extension/theme provided in Elite shipped, or it could be something another developer has done to the system.

When you disable to cache in Magento, the things Magento would normally pull from cache need to be regenerated.  That means more, and different, code runs.  Turning cache back on won't fix this, and Magento first needs to cache something before it can pull it from cache.  My best guess as to what happened is a developer was working on something in the `app/code/local/Elite` folder, something that normally isn't called when the system is cached.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very thorough. I will be sure to post the exact fix once I find it so others who might run into the same issue will have the answer but I am pretty sure this will lead me in the right direction. You're right, as an avid unix/linux user I should have known better then to put a space in the directory name :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your SQL syntax, try the following.

```
UPDATE `core_cache_option` SET value=1;
```

Should be

```
UPDATE `core_cache_option` SET `value`='1';
```

Comment: Where's the error?  `VALUE` is not a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/reserved-words.html) (whereas `VALUES` is).

Comment: Thank you, I ran the updated SQL statement but that did not seem to solve my problem.

Comment: According to his original query, he refers to "value" as a column name rather than a reserved word, which should be surrounded by two ``s, as well as the actual int he wants to set it to should be surrounded by ''s.

Comment: Wrong, wrong, wrong.  `value` is a perfectly valid object name, even when unqualified and unquoted.  Quoting the literal value changes it from a numeric type to a string type, which is probably not correct (but MySQL's implicit type conversion will transparently fix it for you).

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding my problem. I am not receiving errors when running the sql statement, I am having problems with magento. The sql statement was ran in attempt to fix my errors in magento.